# Do I have to deploy ConnectedService.json file in ConnectedService.json folder?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I'm deploying an API project in .Net 6 using Visual Studio (publish command).

I noticed that the file ConnectedService.json is included into my deployment in the ConnectedService folder.

**ConnectedService.json**

```json
{
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "http://localhost/myservice/myservice.asmx"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, MyNamespace"
    ],
    "sync": true,
    "targetFramework": "net6.0",
    "typeReuseMode": "All"
  }
}
```

I would like to know if I need to publish this file considering the services URL is in my *appsettings.json* and I used it in the following way:

```cs
using (MySoapClient mySoapClient = new MySoapClient(MySoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.MySoap))
{
     mySoapClient.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:MyWSEndpoint").Value);
     ...
}
```

Note: I know I can use partial `ConfigureEndpoint` to configure the URL.